# How to get rid of Mackeeper.zerobit pop-up from Safari

Tags: macos, mac, malware, safari

Whenever I open any link or search for anything that has the word Mac, Computer, Keeper, etc. A new tab opens with an advertisement for MacKeeper. The website is called

```
http://mackeeperapp.zeobit.com/landings/17/index.php?affid=zzb_198.2691564.1408407869.5.zzb&utm_source=N%2FA&utm_medium=zzb_3059&utm_campaign=mk_nvrbl_us_ff&utm_term=&utm_content=mk_nvrbl_us_ff&userDefiner=zzb_3059&installer=mk_nvrbl_us_ff&trt=29_210312&tid_ext=77856;1928157913
```

Just to be clear, I have not downloaded anything related to mackeeper or zeobit or `mackeeper.zeobit`, so deleting files (that won’t be there) won’t help!!

Safari is really more of a nuisance now, that a helpful web browser, and I generally really like Safari... Please help!

Comment: Guess what you do have the adware installed because of the behavior your describe

Comment: Do you use AdBlock?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: @Scott: I'm not a Mac guy so I'm not familiar with how much overlap there might be.  Our canonical question focuses on Windows.  Would any of that be useful for a Mac?

Answer (score -1):

MacKeeper is well known ransom-ware. Go to “Applications > Utilities > Activity Monitor” Open Activity Monitor and in the filter box type “kee”
Is MacKeeper listed as running?

Also check the file:

```
/etc/hosts
```

For any reference to MacKeeper or zeobit

You will need `root` access to edit the `/etc/hosts` file.

Does the same thing happen if you use Firefox rather than Safari?
If yes, then it is most likely the `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: How would the hosts file being changed lead to the browser opening tabs on its own?